# Freemarker : OSGI Bundle Exception

Tags: spring, osgi, freemarker, equinox

I am very new to OSGI. I am trying to add a new library, FreeMarker to an existing application which uses Spring 3. We are using Equinox. Below are the changes I made,

Added Freemarker dependency in the pom.xml,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

I hope this jar is OSGI complaint.

In the `Import-Package` section I added `com.springsource.freemarker;version="2.3.18"`

In `Bundle-ClassPath` I added, `lib/com.springsource.freemarker-2.3.18.jar`

When I deploy the application, I am getting the below error,

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.springsource.freemarker; version="2.3.18"
```

Please let me know the missing configuration.

Thanks in Advance,
SD

Answer (score 0):

The bundle com.springsource.freemarker does not export the package with the same name. You are mixing the Bundle-SymbolicName with the package name you want to import.

See the Exported Packages section at http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.freemarker&version=2.3.18 to see what you can Import in another bundle.

Comment: +1 this sounds like a reasonable explanation. `Import-Package` should basically reflect the aggregated import statements in the Java sources. As such, you shouldn't have to maintain it manually. Are you building with Maven bundle plugin? That should generate the `Import-Package` header automatically.